# Swift UITableViewCell detailTextLabel.text throws error 'fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None'

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

This is my Swift code to generate my table view. I am trying to set up a tableView with detail labels. I believe that the problem is created because

```
if (cell == nil) {
            println("1")
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CellSubtitle")
            //cell = tableViewCell
        }
```

is never called, therefore the cell is never initialized with the `UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle` style. Here is the needed code for the method:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    println("start TableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath")
    var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellSubtitle") as UITableViewCell
    if (cell == nil) {
        println("1")
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CellSubtitle")
        //cell = tableViewCell
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = instructions[indexPath.row].text
    println("2")
    //cell.detailTextLabel
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = "HI"
    println("3")
```

Here is the console output for the method:

```
start load
1
2
done load
start TableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath
2
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
(lldb)
```

How can I initialize the `detailTextLabel` in order to insert text? When I try to set the text for the label, I receive  `fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None`. Why am I receiving this error?

The cell was not created in a story board. I initialized the cell or registered its class using `tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellSubtitle")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you made your cell in the storyboard, so that's why the "if" clause is never called. You just need to change the cell's style to be "Subtitle" in the inspector in the storyboard (and delete that if clause).

Comment: I did not make the cell in my storyboard. I am initializing the cell using `tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellSubtitle")`

Comment: @jbman223, using that method only gives you the "basic" type cell. Just delete that line, and then your code should work, because the initial dequeue will return a nil cell, which will cause your if clause to be entered.

Comment: @jbman223, did that work? It only worked for me if I changed your "as UITableViewCell" in the dequeue method to "as UITableViewCell!", otherwise I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience so far, because detailTextLabel is optional, you have to type it like this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "whatever"
```

However, the guy above is right, get rid of the registerClass line. I don't use that one and I'm not sure what it's for just yet.

Comment: it works for me. That's because I use the storyboard, and should not need self.tableView.registerClass().